# SPFx - Gulp serve fails

Tags: office-365, spfx, spfx-webparts, sharepoint-framework, gulp

I had 2 webparts in my solution. But when i tried to add the 3rd webpart, it successfully adds. But after that "gulp serve" fails. Below is the error message

D:\Bloom\Code\BloomWebparts>gulp serve

Build target: DEBUG

D:\Bloom\Code\BloomWebparts\node_modules\@microsoft\sp-build-web\node_modules\@m
icrosoft\node-core-library\lib\JsonSchema.js:178
            throw new Error(prefix + os.EOL +
            ^

Error: JSON validation failed:
D:\Bloom\Code\BloomWebparts\config\tslint.json

Error: #/ (Defines configuration options for the...)
       Additional properties not allowed: lintConfig,useDefaultConfigAsBase,remo
veExistingRules,displayAsWarning
    at validateObjectWithCallback (D:\Bloom\Code\BloomWebparts\node_modules\@mic
rosoft\sp-build-web\node_modules\@microsoft\node-core-library\lib\JsonSchema.js:
178:19)
    at JsonSchema.validateObjectWithCallback (D:\Bloom\Code\BloomWebparts\node_m
odules\@microsoft\sp-build-web\node_modules\@microsoft\node-core-library\lib\Jso
nSchema.js:193:13)
    at JsonSchema.validateObject (D:\Bloom\Code\BloomWebparts\node_modules\@micr
osoft\sp-build-web\node_modules\@microsoft\node-core-library\lib\JsonSchema.js:1
75:14)
    at TslintCmdTask._readConfigFile (D:\Bloom\Code\BloomWebparts\node_modules\@
microsoft\sp-build-web\node_modules\@microsoft\gulp-core-build\lib\tasks\GulpTas
k.js:308:28)
    at TslintCmdTask.onRegister (D:\Bloom\Code\BloomWebparts\node_modules\@micro
soft\sp-build-web\node_modules\@microsoft\gulp-core-build\lib\tasks\GulpTask.js:
87:32)
    at Object.initialize (D:\Bloom\Code\BloomWebparts\node_modules\@microsoft\sp
-build-web\node_modules\@microsoft\gulp-core-build\lib\index.js:299:24)
    at SPWebBuildRig.initialize (D:\Bloom\Code\BloomWebparts\node_modules\@micro
soft\sp-build-web\node_modules\@microsoft\sp-build-common\lib\BuildRig.js:61:19)

```
at SPWebBuildRig.initialize (D:\Bloom\Code\BloomWebparts\node_modules\@micro
```

soft\sp-build-web\node_modules\@microsoft\sp-build-common\lib\SPBuildRig.js:22:1
5)
    at SPWebBuildRig.initialize (D:\Bloom\Code\BloomWebparts\node_modules\@micro
soft\sp-build-web\lib\SPWebBuildRig.js:15:15)
    at Object.exports.initialize (D:\Bloom\Code\BloomWebparts\node_modules\@micr
osoft\sp-build-web\lib\index.js:23:17)
    at Object. (D:\Bloom\Code\BloomWebparts\gulpfile.js:7:7)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)

D:\Bloom\Code\BloomWebparts>

**Any idea why this happens?**

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your `tslint.json` file was modified unexpectedly.

You can try to save your `tslint.json` before adding the third web part. Then add it and restore original `tslint.json`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Sergei. But I have already tried that. Same solution works fine in my colleague's environment. He is able to add new webparts and build it without issue. I took his tslint file and tried that also.. No luck. I tried creating a new solution and used that tslint.json. Same issue exists

Comment: Hmm.. in that case for me it looks like a version issue. Have you updated your SPFx generator recently?

Comment: I don't think so. But I am new to SPFx. So maybe I would have done something without actually knowing it.. Anyway to confirm it , in package.json i have this - "@microsoft/generator-sharepoint": "^1.6.0",

Comment: Did your two previous webparts were created with 1.6 version?

Comment: I created those 2 webparts a week back. But I am not sure about the version. any way to find that?

Comment: I created a new solution in a different directory . But now the version shows - @microsoft/generator-sharepoint": "1.5.1".. So what has happened. Any way to revert this?

Comment: So your webparts use 1.6, but you have 1.5.1 locally. You should use the same version for all webparts. Update you genenrator `npm install @microsoft/sharepoint -g`, then try again adding the third web part

Comment: Sergei - I guess my local is having and 1.6 and 2 webparts are having 1.5.1.. So I uninstalled sharepoint generator and reinstalled with 1.5.1.... But still when i create it fails

Comment: How did you install 1.5.1?

Comment: using npm install -g @microsoft/generator-sharepoint@1.5.1

Comment: For this i have moved all my solutions to a new folder and installed ms generator 1.5.1 locally. It worked fine..  Thanks for your support Sergei